# Make discussions a specific part of Chess.SE

Tags: feature-request

There are many questions on Chess.SE which are more discussion-based than pure right-and-wrong. This is the nature of chess, with so many possibilities. Should we add a new question format for discussions? This is to address the existence of questions such as the following:

[How to repair black's position in this Game?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/5763/how-to-repair-blacks-position-in-this-game)

[Can Black reach full equality in this game?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/5452/can-black-reach-full-equality-in-this-game)

[What plan should black have followed in this game?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/4938/what-plan-should-black-have-followed-in-this-game)

[Colle System - Stonewall. Why not c4 and b4 after b5 and c6 for black in this game?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/12817/colle-system-stonewall-why-not-c4-and-b4-after-b5-and-c6-for-black-in-this-ga)

[How to continue in this game?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/14713/how-to-continue-in-this-game)

All of these questions require discussion-style answers, so would it be worth it to create a new format for starting a discussion? Ideas could include the following:

1. Simply create a [discussion] tag which labels a question as a discussion. In one of these questions, the OP cannot select a 'right' answer since there could be multiple answers. Instead, the answers are purely ranked by votes.
2. Add a 'create discussion' button next to 'ask question'. Ideas include having a question-style post, but changing the comment system so that you can post an answer as an "answer to another answer". This way, posting pgn as a reply is possible, and you are not limited to the format of regular comments. Allowing people to post pgn in comments allows them to reply to answers by displaying possible other variations in the game.

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion, the current format of Stack Exchange already supports these kind of 'discussions' very well. Some subjective questions are allowed, as per the [help center](https://chess.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask):

> **Some subjective questions are allowed, but “subjective” does not mean “anything goes”. All subjective questions are expected to be *constructive*.** What does that mean? Constructive subjective questions:
>
> - inspire answers that explain “why” and “how”
> - tend to have long, not short, answers
> - have a constructive, fair, and impartial tone
> - invite sharing experiences over opinions
> - insist that opinion be backed up with facts and references
> - are more than just mindless social fun

So, if the question is not something like "what's your favourite opening", there's plenty of room for constructive discussion.

<sub>P.S. Chess SE is such a small site that it is unlikely the developers will build new functionality for it – I'm already more than happy with the built-in PGN viewer.</sub>

Comment: I hadn't noticed this, i assumed it was like the other SE sites. Maybe just add a [discussion] tag which says something along the lines of "This question is to promote ideas and may not have one 'right' answer". (Similar to the [reality-check] and [hard-science] tags in worldbuilding). Perhaps even put [Discussion] in the title of the question whenever this tag is used.