# Are questions involving opinions allowed?

Tags: discussion, site-scope, questions

I have got a question about asking questions about opinions: Why are they not allowed? As far as I know, I don't find anything wrong with them.

And, if this question is closed, that would be a philosophical contradiction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Questions about opinions *are* allowed under some circumstances, highlighted in the Help Center article [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). First, what kind of questions are not allowed:

> If your motivation for asking the question is “I would like to participate in a discussion about ______”, then you should not be asking here.

> To prevent your question from being flagged and possibly removed, avoid asking subjective questions where ...
>
> - every answer is equally valid: “What’s your favorite ______?”
> - your answer is provided along with the question, and you expect more answers: “I use ______ for ______, what do you use?”
> - there is no actual problem to be solved: “I’m curious if other people feel like I do.”
> - you are asking an open-ended, hypothetical question: “What if ______ happened?”
> - your question is just a rant in disguise: “______ sucks, am I right?”

Second, what kind of opinion-based questions *are* allowed?

> Some subjective questions are allowed, but “subjective” does not mean “anything goes”. All subjective questions are expected to be constructive. What does that mean? Constructive subjective questions:
>
> - inspire answers that explain “why” and “how”
> - tend to have long, not short, answers
> - have a constructive, fair, and impartial tone
> - invite sharing experiences over opinions
> - insist that opinion be backed up with facts and references
> - are more than just mindless social fun
>
> For more detail, read about our [guidelines for great subjective questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/) and blog post about how [real questions have answers](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/real-questions-have-answers/).

Of course, there is a gray area; for those cases, we have the review queues where the community can decide whether a question is appropriate for Chess Stack Exchange or not.

Comment: So, in short, "why do top players refuse to play the King's Gambit?" is a valid question despite multiple opinions being possible, while "Do you like the King's Gambit?" is not

Comment: Although I can see the purpose of the opinion-ban, I think this is frequently misused. Someone wants to close a question, and reaches for an excuse that is suitably vague. There is no explanation given at the time of why the closure has to happen. The questioner is left baffled and powerless. Two of the question templates that you list as objectionable I find completely ok.
- your answer is provided along with the question, and you expect more answers: “I use ______ for ______, what do you use?”
- you are asking an open-ended, hypothetical question: “What if ______ happened?”

Comment: What is meant by the point "Constructive subjective questions: .. • invite sharing experiences over opinions" in the chess.SE context?

Answer (score 0):

> As far as I know, I don't find anything wrong with them.

In that case, go away and set up your own "ReinstateMonicaExchange" site where such questions are allowed. This site is not all about you. It's about all of us.

Joking aside, the first thing you need to do is go away and read the relevant topics in the [Help Center](https://chess.stackexchange.com/help). Read all of it, but pay particular attention to what it says about [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask).

The key point is that suitable questions should have definitive answers. If my opinion on a subject is different from yours and both are arguable then the question is not suitable. The site is not supposed to be about arguments and discussions. It's supposed to be about facts.

Another relevant answer to this question is [this one](https://chess.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/433/make-discussions-a-specific-part-of-chess-se/434#434) from Glorfindel.

Coming back to:

> And, if this question is closed, that would be a philosophical
> contradiction.

Depends on why it would be closed. For instance if it were closed for being a duplicate of [this question](https://chess.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/433/make-discussions-a-specific-part-of-chess-se). It isn't, so it hasn't been.

Comment: Who's Monica anyway and why should we reinstate her?

Comment: That doesn't strike me as an example of "joking". It seems completely humourless, saying "well that's the way we do things round here: too bad - just leave if you don't like it." It's not about the small group of folks who happen to be in meta and chess right now, it's about making something for tens of thousands of people who are not here, because they are not made sufficiently welcome. You can pick on the rare newcomers one at a time and say they are in the minority so they'd better leave. That will guarantee that this community stays tiny even in the post-"Queen's Gambit" age.